# Returning to Command Line Interface in ubuntu server

Tags: command-line, server

I am running Ubuntu Server with the Xfce desktop environment install.
I have to type `startx` to get to the GUI.  How can I get back into the command line interface when I am in the GUI without rebooting.

Comment: For clarity, are you just wanting to access the command line, or are you wanting to quit your X session?

Answer (score 1):

You can change your `tty` and there are several ways to do that, e.g:

```
sudo chvt 2
```

Will put you in `tty2`.

or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>.

use `ps $(pgrep  X)` command to see in which `tty` your `X` session is running, and use another.

You can also kill the `X` session which is not a good idea, or change the target to `multiuser.target`.

Alternatively you might want to stop `xfce4-session`:

```
sudo pkill -15 xfce4-session
```

Comment: You mean CTRL-ALT-F2, correct?